# Magmi not importing product type

Tags: magento, csv, import, product, magmi

I have just started using Magmi to upload products but keep running into a problem.  My products are uploading ok but when I look in the admin section they have not been assigned a product type.  Also when you look at the product it is missing all of the price information etc.  I have tried reindexing both in the admin and via Magmi Reindexer as sugested in other questions but it doesn't make any difference.

The CSV file I am using is as follows:

```
"sku","store","attribute_set","type","grouped_skus","categories","brands","color","delivery_availability","description","enable_googlecheckout","gallery","guarantee","image","image_label","ip_rating","lighting_fitting_system","lighting_light_colour","media_gallery","meta_description","meta_keyword","meta_title","name","package_id","price","product_category","short_description","small_image","small_image_label","special_from_date","special_price","special_to_date","status","style","tax_class_id","thumbnail","thumbnail_label","type","url_key","url_path","visibility","voltage","weight"
"SY7031CC",,"Lighting","simple",,"Lighting/Kitchen Lighting/Under Cabinet Lights;;Lighting/Kitchen Lighting/Down Lights",,"Chrome","3 Working Days","Required when using 60&deg; and 120&deg; beam angles",1,,"3 Year Guarantee",,,,"LED Plug in System",,,,,,"Surface Spacer for 60&deg; and 120&deg; Florence, Toscanna, Siclia Lights - Chrome","3 Working Days",3.95,,"For use with Florence, Siclia and Toscana 3 Watt OSRAM LED light fittings.",,,,,,1,,2,,,"Accessories","Surface-Spacer-for-60&deg;-and-120&deg;-Florence-Toscanna-Siclia-Lights-Chrome","Surface-Spacer-for-60&deg;-and-120&deg;-Florence-Toscanna-Siclia-Lights-Chrome.html",1,,0.3
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the `type` column defined twice in your CSV.

The first instance has the correct value, `simple`.  The second instance of type has `Accessories` as the value.

You need to remove the second instance of type, as `Accessories` is not a valid value for the type column.  Additionally, you cannot use `type` for custom attribute data.  It's a Magento reserved attribute for defining the product type.  Try creating an attribute named `product_type` instead, and setting the `Frontend Label` to `Type`.  This will allow you to set the data, without conflicting with the core Magento attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help Axel, it solved the problem straight away.  I had been using 'type' for products uploaded using standard magento CSV upload with no problems but I am running magento 1.5 and I think the '_type' used for products types (simple etc.) must have made it possible.